# What part of the auction process for U.S. Treasuries makes it impossible to enroll in the auto-rollover feature after the initial order entry?

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds, treasury, auction

When trying to activate auto-rollover for an already purchased Treasury security on Schwab, I get the message:

> This security is ineligible for auto-rollover. Due to the nature of the auction process for U.S. Treasuries, you must enroll in the auto-rollover feature at the initial order entry.

What part of the auction process for U.S. Treasuries makes it impossible to enroll in the auto-rollover feature after the initial order entry?

---

I tried to activate auto-rollover for these Treasury Bills:

| CUSIP | Security Description |
| --- | --- |
| 912796CT4 | 17-Week Bill |
| 912796CW7 | 17-Week Bill |
| 912796YH6 | 52-Week Bill |
| 912796Z93 | 17-Week Bill |
| 912797FD4 | 17-Week Bill |

Answer (score -4):

Bogleheads user [aspiringboglehead](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=29669) [pointed](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=7163989#p7163989) me to the following:

> TreasuryDirect lets you make a change after an initial purchase:
> [treasurydirect.gov/.../#reinvest](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/help/treasurydirect-help/how-do-i/#reinvest). It may just be a limitation of the interface that Treasury provides to the brokers.

[treasurydirect.gov/.../#reinvest](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/help/treasurydirect-help/how-do-i/#reinvest) indeed indicates that one may schedule reinvestments after making one's original purchase (aka auto-rollover):

> **Scheduling reinvestments after making your original purchase.** If you have an original or reinvested security which has no reinvestments scheduled, you may request reinvestment of the security prior to its maturity.
>
> - Log into your primary TreasuryDirect® account.
> - Click the ManageDirect tab at the top of the page.
> - Select the Schedule Reinvestments text link.
> - Select the type of security you wish to reinvest and click **"Submit"**. A page will display with your eligible securities which have no reinvestments scheduled.
> - Choose the security(ies) you wish to reinvest, insert the number of reinvestments requested, and click **"Submit"**.
> - A message will display confirming your reinvestment request.
>
> Note: To change the number of scheduled reinvestments for a security, select the Edit Reinvestments link on ManageDirect.

Schwab misleads their clients by putting the blame on the auction process.